# Why does python return an error when I write two functions within one class object

Tags: python-2.7

my code is:

```
class Solution(object):

    def getRow(self, rowIndex):
        """
        :type rowIndex: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        if rowIndex == 0:
            return [1]
        elif rowIndex == 1:
            return [1, 1]
        else:
            ini_row = [1, 2, 1]

            def GenNextRow(ini_row):
                return map(lambda x, y: x+y, [0] + ini_row, ini_row + [0])

            while len(ini_row) < rowIndex+1:
                ini_row = GenNextRow(ini_row)

            return ini_row

    def getRow2(self, rowIndex):
        result = [0] * (rowIndex + 1)
        for i in xrange(rowIndex + 1):
            old = result[0] = 1
            for j in xrange(1, i+1):
                old, result[j] = result[j], old + result[j]
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    result = Solution().getRow2(4)
    end_time = time.time()
    print 'result: {0}'.format(result)
    print 'time: {0}'.format(end_time-start_time)
```

However, when I run it from terminal, I get an error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "array-Pascal's_Triangle2.py", line 46, in 
>       result = Solution().getRow2(4)
>   AttributeError: 'Solution' object has no attribute 'getRow2'

Then I tried to annotate the first function `getRow()`, the `Solution.getRow2()` run successfully...

Comment: Yes, it is indeed an indentation problem. I copied a few lines of codes from leetcode website into sublime, which contain whitespace and mixed with tab indentation later on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the GenNextRow function outside the class as Python doesn't understand why there is a badly indented method in the class. Do this instead:

```
 def GenNextRow(ini_row):
                return map(lambda x, y: x+y, [0] + ini_row, ini_row + [0])

 class Solution(object):
    [...]
```